# Как переписать цикл for в reducer?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, объекты

господа. Прошу помочь со следующим вопросом.
Есть цикл:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < arrayOfSizes.length; i++) {
          if (arrayOfSizes[i].offset < arrayOfSizes[i - 1].offset) {
            offset += arrayOfSizes[i].offset;
          }
        }
```

Он перебирает массив с объектами, и суммирует значения "offset", если текущий меньше предыдущего.
Нужно переписать его через reducer, чтобы получилось что то типа этого:

```js
const offset = arrayOfSizes.reduce(
          (prev: any, val: any, i: any, arr: any) =>
            val.offset < arr[i].offset ? prev + val.offset : prev,
          0,
        );
```

У меня в коде ошибка, но пока не могу понять в чем.

Comment: `val.offset < arr[i].offset`, разве `val` не равно `arr[i]`?

Comment: я до этого, когда просто перебирал массив только с Offset, написал через reducer. Теперь я переписал setState и теперь у меня в массиве, объекты с значениями height и offset, примерно следующего вида:
[{height: 123, offset: 12}, ....]. И за за того что нужно перебирать объекты я запутался)

Comment: Я вам о другом. В чем смысл условия `val.offset < arr[i].offset`? Оно не будет всегда ложным? Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Смысл следующий, цикл перебирает массив, и если текущее просматриваемое значение, меньше чем предыдущее, текущий суммируется.

Comment: По сути, к вашему примеру добавить условие i > 0 (элемент не превый) и взять предыдущий элемент вместо текущего (arr[i - 1]) и всё: `.reduce((prev, val,  i, arr) => i > 0 && val.offset < arr[i-1].offset ? prev + val.offset : prev, 0)` при этом, первый элемент не включается в сумму.

Comment: @Madiever, я пытаюсь вам сказать, что вы не сравниваете текущее с предыдущим, вы сравниваете текущее значение с текущим => ошибка :)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю как-то так

```js
let arrayOfSizes = [{offset: 1},{offset: 2},{offset: 3},{offset: 4},{offset: 5},{offset: 4},{offset: 3},{offset: 2},{offset: 1}];

let result = arrayOfSizes.reduce( (acc, item, index) => {
 acc += (index >= 1 && item.offset < arrayOfSizes[index - 1].offset) ? item.offset : 0;
 return acc;
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```